# IsNumeric returns unexpected true/false

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a variable which can be a string or number. So I am checking if it's a number with `IsNumeric(var)`. But when `var = 2` `IsNumeric` returns false? I can put `var` in a `Round()` and the statement returns true. But if var is a string the code will throw error: Type Mismatch.

How `var` is set:

```
strSQL = "SELECT id,name, number FROM Person "
Set rs = myConn.Execute(strSQL)
If IsNull(var) Then
    var = Session("LoginID")
End If
```

`IsNumeric(var)` ← returns false when `var = 2`.

`IsNumeric(Round(var))` ← returns true when `var = 2` and throws error when var is a string.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where the `var` variable is being set, so difficult to make the same assumption you are.

Below is a quick test script showing some possible outcomes from `IsNumeric()`.

```
Option Explicit

Dim value
Dim values: values = Array(2, "2", "2 ", "", Nothing, Null)
For Each value In values
  Call Response.Write("IsNumeric = " & IsNumeric(value))
Next
```

Output:

```
IsNumeric = True
IsNumeric = True
IsNumeric = True
IsNumeric = False
IsNumeric = False
IsNumeric = False
```

Comment: I have tested:
response.write var  <-- prints 2
response.write IsNumeric(V_InternBehandler)  <-- false
response.write IsNumeric(round(V_InternBehandler)) <-- true

And i cant make sense of it

Comment: Show us where you assign 'var' as Lankymart pointed out.  My guess is that you are getting it from recordset.Fields and you are grabbing the object it is returning instead of the value.  'Round' will coerce it into a value and exhibit the behavior you are seeing.